# Is Siri able to recognise a contact nickname and action on it?

Tags: iphone, contacts, siri

I want to call my girlfriend using Siri. The problem is that her name is Hungarian and I am not able to pronounce it in a way that Siri recognise it and call her. So I thought that I give her a nickname "girlfriend" and ask Siri to "call my girlfriend". This does not work. Siri asks me who my girlfriend is even though her nickname is defined as "girlfriend"

So what is the easiest way for me to call her using Siri? I have 2,000 names in my contact list with many first names that are the same like her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Contacts app, edit your girlfriend's card to give her a `Relationship` of `girlfriend`. This will solve your problem in the most official of ways.

See more detail [here](http://forums.imore.com/iphone-4s/234977-siri-4s-how-manually-add-relationship-data-contacts.html).

Comment: Thank you. 
As I see this will only work if I am using icloud contacts, because gmail or corporate contacts kept in the iphone do not necessarily have "relationship" fields.

Comment: Ok, maybe a reason to use iCloud :). You can check off this answer if it is a good one, to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a phonetic name that will help Siri understand.

Edit the contact, and scroll to the very bottom of the contact info. Tap **Add Field**, then choose **Phonetic First Name** or **Phonetic Last Name**. Fill in the field with a phonetic spelling of the name you want Siri to pronounce or understand. Use combinations of letters that make the best sense for phonetic spelling, and you’ll get better results.

So in your case, you can try to set **Phonetic First Name** to "my girlfriend". Note that if you set it to just "girlfriend", Siri might have problems if you say "my girlfriend".

One strange side effect of this, is that the contacts list uses the phonetic name for sorting, so in this example your girlfriend will be sorted in the contacts list uas "my girlfriend", and not the original spelling.

Comment: I tried this too and Siri tried to call me! :)
I will continue to play with this as obviously something is happening.